# How to replace output in console if string changing in length

Tags: python

I know about the use of '\r' in python, however it does not work on strings shortening in length (example shown below):

```
import time
List = ['a','b','c','d','e']
for i in range(5, 0, -1):
    print(''.join(List[0:i]), end = '\r')
    time.sleep(1)
# Will always output 'abcde'
```

Lets assume i wanted to output the following:
'abcde'
Next iteration line 1 shows:
'adcd'
second iteration line 1 shows:
'abc'
etc ...
How would I go about this?
Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use python3 and replace print statement by `print('\r' + ''.join(List[0:i]) + ' '*(5-i), end='')`, maybe you will get what you want.

complete code:

```
import time
List = ['a','b','c','d','e']
for i in range(5, 0, -1):
    print('\r' + ''.join(List[0:i]) + ' '*(5-i), end='')
    time.sleep(1)
```